# Permutation representation definition

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

I have come across the following definition of a permutation representation.

"a permutation representation is a representation of the form C[X] for a G-set X"

However I am struggling to match this with other definitions I have seen. Does C[X] here refer to the polynomial ring? Could anyone provide an example using this definition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take the vector space with basis $X$. Then define an action on this vector space using the existing $G$-action on $X$. Every group element will be mapped to a permutation matrix of some kind.

Comment: Thank you, that has helped with my understanding of what permutation representations mean. Does that mean C[X] here refers to the set of permutation matrices?

Comment: No, $C[X]$ refers to the vector space with basis indexed by the set $X$. (I would usually call this $CX$ rather than $C[X]$, but the notation here is kind of non-standard either way).